# Firebase Functions Error: InternalError Too Much Recursion

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm building a function in Firebase that deletes a document and all it's sub-collections by following [this tutorial](https://fireship.io/snippets/delete-firestore-collection/). When I try to run the function, I get the below response:

> Failure: InternalError: Too Much Recursion

Here is my index.js in Firebase Functions:

```
const project = process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT;
const token = functions.config().ci_token;

exports.deletePath = functions.region("australia-southeast1").runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 540 })
.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    // TODO: Add auth here.
    const path = data.path;
    
    return firebase_tools.firestore
        .delete(path, {
            project,
            token,
            recursive: true,
            yes: true
    }).then(() => ({ result: "Deleted successfully." }));
});
```

And here is where I call it in app:

```
let deleteFunction = firebase.functions().httpsCallable("deletePath");
let path = db.collection("posts").doc(this.postId);

deleteFunction({ path: path }).then(result => {
  console.log("Success: " + result);
}).catch(e => {
  console.log("Failure: " + e);
})
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the issue. There were a few things:

1. I wasn't declaring what region I was calling in app. Since add a declaration:

```
var functions= firebase.app().functions("australia-southeast1");
```

2. I wasn't declaring firebase_tools in my index.js
3. "path" is a string, not a reference to the actual collection. So in this case, I now pass "posts/docId".